# Is there a Checkpoint client for Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, vpn

I use checkpoint VPN software to connect to my office network on windows.

I tried a lot to configure the same on ubuntu VPN, but never succeeded.

Anyone aware of any specific software/steps to configure vpn. I connect using a gateway and random pin generation token.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VPNClient

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out jay..Over and Above it would me greatfull if you help me to configure site for VPN..I have installed VPN Checkpoint client In Ubuntu 12.4 LTS..